# Package kernel-package has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, kernel, aptitude

I want to install kernel package  by this command

```
sudo apt-get install kernel-package
```

but it gives me the error :

```
Package kernel-package has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by Update My package Repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```